# simple JavaScript array code error, pickup array`s element and delete

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to push 1 or 2 or 3 without reputation to nosamenumbers array.
but, console sometimes give me output [1,1] [2,2].

I choose one number in numbers array then I pushed to noSameNumbers, then I erase the literal I choose in array.

and did same code but console give me strange data.

Why?

```
var noSameNumbers = [];
var numbers = [1,2,3];

var what = numbers[ Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length) ];
noSameNumbers[0] = what;
numbers.splice(what,1);

var what2 = numbers[ Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length) ];
noSameNumbers[1] = what2;

console.log(noSameNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers.splice is incorrect, hence the same number has a chance of being selected twice as it is not actually being removed from the array (rather, an incorrect number is being removed from the array).

Instead of saying what item you want to remove from the array, you instead want to pass into the function the **index** of the item you want to remove from the array. See [array.prototype.splice on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

In order to find the index of the item you're trying to remove from the array, use [array.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Your fixed code:

```
var noSameNumbers = [];
var numbers = [1,2,3];

var what = numbers[ Math.floor(Math.random()*numbers.length) ];
noSameNumbers[0] = what;
numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(what),1); // this is the line I changed

var what2 = numbers[ Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length) ];
noSameNumbers[1] = what2;

console.log(noSameNumbers);
```